# Python while loop UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I need a function with a while loop, that as long as the condition is False calls the function again.

This code will obviously result in a endless loop since "i" is always re declared as "0":

```
def fun():
    i = 0
# does something else
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
        fun()
    print('done') 

fun()
```

So I see no other way than to go about it like this:

```
i = 0

def fun():
# does something else
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
        fun()
    print('done') 
fun()
```

But with this code It says local variable 'i' referenced before assignment.
I don't get it what am I doing wrong here?
I know I could use an if statement here, but that would be much more complicated and can get in my way in the project, although its not impossible.

Comment: Put the while loop outside the function.

Comment: `def fun(i=0):` initialize i locally to that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the value i has not been declared in the function, so the function doesn't know what i is. There are a couple of ways to fix this.

One way is to put the while loop OUTSIDE of the function. This is how it would look like:

```python
i = 0

def fun():
    #Do Something...
    print('done') 

while i < 5:
    i += 1
    fun()
```

Another way would be to add the parameter i into the function. You do this by adding i into the brackets. This is how it would look like:

```python
i = 0

def fun(i): #I Added An i Here So That The Function Knows We Need A Value Of i
    #Do Something...
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
        fun(i) #I Use The Same Value Of i Set At The Beginning
    print('done') 
fun(i) #I Call The Function Again
```

You could also set i as a global variable, meaning it can be used in the function too. To do that, just add `global` and the variable. This is how I did it:

```python
i = 0

def fun():
    global i
    #Do Something...
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
        fun()
    print('done') 
fun()
```

If neither of these 3 methods work, you could try and maybe use a for loop: something like `for i in range(0, 5):` , which would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Since other posts has offered remedy already, here I just point out the reason more detail:
This is one of the common `gotchas` to the new learners, the reason is that -

- it's because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope.

In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is `assigned` a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
It can be a surprise to get the UnboundLocalError in previously working code when it is modified by `adding an assignment statement` somewhere in the body of a function.

Answer (score 0):

variable `i` is not in the scope of the function. Hence it is not accessible.

I believe the below code will help you get the desired output.

```
def fun(count):
    # does something else
    if(count >= 5):
        return
    fun(count + 1)
    print('done')

fun(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you are looking for:

```
def fun(i=0):
    # does something else
    result = True
    while result:
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
        while i >= 5:
            result = False
            break
    print('done')
fun()
```